# How can I show the name on the UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to display the name on the `UIView` but it returns `null` value, here is my code:

```
SchedulingCustomModel *scheduling = [[SchedulingCustomModel alloc]init];
lblphysicianName=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 5,self.view.frame.size.width-10,20)];
lblphysicianName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",scheduling.physicianName];
lblphysicianName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblphysicianName.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
lblphysicianName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
lblphysicianName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[viewMonthAndHolidays addSubview:lblphysicianName];
```

Comment: You are doing initialization of instance `scheduling` that means this object has a new memory address and it will not contain the previous values. 
Rather than this making a singleton class can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`scheduling.physicianName` might be nil....

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forget to give you `scheduling.physicianName` a non-null value.
So make sure your custom model `scheduling` is not null.Then you'll see what you want.